# use html code in .php file but not interpret

Tags: php, html

I use html code in php file but html code not interpret and show code in browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Lorem Ipsum
</body>
</html>
```

show code above

Comment: What did you want to happen with the html code?

Comment: And what it's output when you run this page? and how's you are running this page?

Comment: are you using an wamp or xampp for viewing php?

Answer (score -1):

HTML code outside php tags does not pass through php interpreter, but if you need the html to pass through it , do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo "Document"; ?></title></head><body>
<?php echo "fkjgfkddjklk"; ?></body></html>
```

Also make sure your file ends with .php extension